# Android Sqlite exclude fields

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist, request

I'm trying this query:

```
Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE Field5 NOT LIKE " + 
Arrays.toString(ALQu.toArray()).replace("[", "(").replace("]", ")") + 
"ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", null);
```

but i get the following error :

`03-12 18:12:34.469: E/AndroidRuntime(16604): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM TableQ WHERE Field5 NOT LIKE (6, 9) ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1`

I try to exclude the already checked fields. I add the data in an ArrayList. I don't see where is the problem. Can you help pls ?

EDIT :

Yes, it's "NOT IN", I don't know why i didn't try it , thanks

Comment: I don't think `NOT LIKE (6, 9)` is SQLite valid

Comment: Maybe you meant "NOT IN (6, 9)" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change NOT LIKE to NOT IN:

```
Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE Field5 NOT IN " + 
    Arrays.toString(ALQu.toArray()).replace("[", "(").replace("]", ")") + 
    "ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", null);
```